# Получение значения из скрипта PHP в Java приложении

Tags: java

Пишу Java-приложение.
В основном пишу на PHP, Java для меня немного далека, но нужно получить значение из скрипта php в приложении Java.

Суть такая: есть файл, к примеру, check.php:

```php
$version = '1.0';
$update = true;

if ($update == true) {
    switch ($_GET['do']) {
        case 'version':
            echo $version;
        break;

        default:
            die('Ошибка! Запрос не может быть обработан');
        break;
    }
}
```

Нужно получить текст в Java-приложении с localhost/check.php?do=version и сравнить его с тем, что будет задано в самом приложении.

Если привести пример на php, то что-то типа:

```php
if ($version > $app_version) {
    $update = true;
} else {
    $update = false;
}
```

Ничего не смог найти в гугле. Может, кто сможет подсказать, в какую сторону хоть смотреть.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [`HttpURLConnection`](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/) (у вас GET-запрос).

Comment: Quercus is Caucho Technology's 100% Java implementation of PHP 5 released under the Open Source GPL license http://quercus.caucho.com/